# How to convert PowerShell code for a batch file?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

This code unblocks a OneDrive library, for the sake of security. The library is found in the `C:\ODTool` directory, and is downloaded form a GitHub online open project. It uses PowerShell to import a module, then run the command `Get-ODStatus`, to determine the sync status of OneDrive, outputting it to `output.csv` in the current directory.

```
PS C:\ODTool> Unblock-File -Path C:\ODTool\OneDriveLib.dll
              Import-Module C:\ODTool\OneDriveLib.dll
              Get-ODStatus > output.csv 2>&1
```

I need to convert this PowerShell script to an executable batch file command.

Comment: Why don't just use PowerShell? And if you want to convert then what have you tried? This isn't a free coding service

Comment: PLEASE use sentences with puctuation. stop to breathe between sentences instead of blurting everything out in one blob ... [*grin*]

Comment: Also what you've posted does not appear to be a PowerShell script, as you stated in your question, but a series of three individual commands entered in a Windows PowerShell window.

Answer (score 1):

Create a txt file and add the following code:

```
@ECHO OFF
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -File  <full path to ps1>
```

then save the file as a .bat

Comment: Other switches may be helpful. `powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -NoProfile -File <full path to ps1>`